# Whats the difference between Shibboleth and OpenId

Tags: openid, federated-identity, shibboleth

I'm evaluating different Federated Identity Provider technologies and wondering what is the difference between Shibboleth and OpenId. It looks to me like both technologies use approximately the same patterns to provide identity services to service providers. How to decide which one to use? Are there any hidden properties that make a difference?

Comment: yes, it is still a question of mine